# Android Multiline autocompletetextview dropdown scroll coming for one item error

Tags: android, multiline, autocompletetextview

I created multiline dropdown items for my Autocompletetextview android. In dropdown Scroll coming for just one or two items check attached screenshots. The Scroll in dropdown should come when the items are more than 5 items. For single multiline item because of scroll full item information visible on scrolling getting cut.

[image]

[image]

**My item XML**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/underline">
    <com.rm.partner.customview.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteSpinnerText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_5dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_textcolor"
        app:fontName_TextView="@string/FONT_PROXIMANOVALIGHT"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Autocomplete Textview**

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
             android:id="@+id/select_scheme_spinner"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="0.90"
             android:background="@android:color/transparent"
             android:hint="@string/autocomplete_hint"
             android:imeOptions="actionDone"
             android:inputType="none"
             android:overlapAnchor="false"
             android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_5dp"
             android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_5dp"
             android:textColor="@color/grey_textcolor"
             android:textColorHint="@color/grey_textcolor"
             android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/custom_cursor_grey"
             android:textSize="@dimen/font_12sp"
             android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView"
             app:fontName_TextView="@string/FONT_PROXIMANOVALIGHT" />
```

**Custom adapter getView**

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        try {
            final ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
            final ClientFolioResponse.ResponseListObjectBean schemeOptionObj = dataSet.get(position);
            final View result;
            if (convertView == null) {
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spiner_item_reft, parent, false);
                viewHolder.schemeName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteSpinnerText);
                result = convertView;
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                result = convertView;
            }
            if (schemeOptionObj.getFolioNo().length()>0) {
                String schemeNameText = schemeOptionObj.getFolioNo() + "/" + schemeOptionObj.getSchemeName();
                viewHolder.schemeName.setText(schemeNameText);
            } else {
                viewHolder.schemeName.setText(schemeOptionObj.getSchemeName());
            }
            result.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext()
                                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        if (imm != null) {
                            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                                    view.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```